# Microsoft Cognitive bing search migration

Tags: python, azure-cognitive-services

Hi Previously I used [py bing search module](https://github.com/tristantao/py-bing-search) in fetching urls using bing search but as there is this new development of old bing search api being obsolete by december 15th wanted to know how can I migrate it to new process from my existing process. Do we have any modules like py-bing-search wrappers which could help us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Author of [py-bing-search](https://github.com/tristantao/py-bing-search) here. I just pushed a simple wrapper for the cognitive search websearch API: [py-ms-cognitive](https://github.com/tristantao/py-ms-cognitive). It's in pre-alpha, but does work. Feel free to try it out via:

```
pip install py-ms-cognitive
```

Would love feedback / issues on the git repo. The goal is to actually provide a wrapper for all Miscrosoft Cognitive Services API, but we'll see how that goes.